# JQuery Как при нажатии по порядку чекбоксов отловливать их названия и отправлять в попап

Tags: jquery, массивы, push

При нажатии последовательно чекбоксов нужно отловливать их названия и отправлять в попап. При каждом нажатии название чекбокса сохраняется в переменную titleServ. Затем название добавляется в массив servicesTitles и выводится методом join в попап.

```
$(".services_list input").change(function(){        
    var titleServ;
    var servicesTitles=[];              
    titleServ=$(this).closest('.labtab').find('.mobileboldtext').text();
    servicesTitles.push(titleServ);
    document.getElementById('vibrani_uslugi').innerHTML = servicesTitles.join(", ");
        
});
```

Но при выводе массив содержит один элемент, не пойму где ошибка

Comment: что за каша опять из js и jquery ? `document.getElementById('vibrani_uslugi').innerHTML` это `$("#vybrani_uslugi").html(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаёте массив каждый раз заново. Попробуйте так:

```
var servicesTitles=[];

$(".services_list input").change(function(){        
    var titleServ; 
    titleServ=$(this).closest('.labtab').find('.mobileboldtext').text();
    servicesTitles.push(titleServ);
    document.getElementById('vibrani_uslugi').innerHTML = servicesTitles.join(", ");
});
```

Comment: Да действительно, как я просмотрел это. Спасибо.